# Syntax for Copy-Item and concatenating a directory\file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy files from one location to another.  I have a CSV that has the directory, name, and some other fields that aren't important for the move.  I'm pretty sure that my code is trying to move the entire folder structure and not just the file.  How can I just move the file? **OR** How can I move a similar folder structure to the new location (\folder\username)

The directory looks something like:

```
\\server\folder\username
```

The code I was trying:

```
Import-Csv c:\movefiles.csv | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -LiteralPath ($_.Directory + "\" + $_.name) -Destination c:\}
```

The destination will actually be a location on another server.

Comment: when you say similar folder structure at the new location, do you mean `c:\folder\username` as destination? just switch out `\\server\ ` with `c:\ ` ?

Comment: If I have another server to move the files to, then the file structure should be \\newserver\folder\username  and then the file located in there.  This was a thought since there are multiple duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code your trying should copy the file(as long as the `name` property is the name of a file) and save it in `c:\` just like you wanted. You might want to use `Join-Path` to combine the directory and filename instead of your current approach. It makes sure that you don't have multiple `\` etc.. Ex:

```
ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -LiteralPath (Join-Path $_.Directory $_.name) -Destination c:\}
```

Copy with folderstructure(untested):

```
function MoveTo-NewServer {
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Csvpath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Newserver)

    if(Test-Path $Csvpath -PathType Leaf) {
        Import-Csv $Csvpath | ForEach-Object {
            $h = ([uri]$_.directory).Host
            $src = Join-Path $_.Directory $_.name
            $dest = $src.Replace($h, $Newserver)
            if(!(Test-Path $dest)) { New-Item $dest -ItemType File -Force }
            Copy-Item -LiteralPath $src -Destination $dest -Force
        }
    }
}
```

As said, this is untested. Try to use it like this:

```
MoveTo-NewServer -Csvpath "c:\mycsv.csv" -Newserver "server2"
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for with the concatenation and it works, but I also want to see if there's an answer about moving the folder structure.

Comment: Keeping folderstructure is more complicated. I updated my answer with an attempt(I didn't have PS so I could test it). It should replace the servername in a unc-path (e.g. `\\server1\folder\sdad\file.txt` to `\\server2\folder\sdad\file.txt`) and copy it. Notice that it only Works on filepaths. To move a folder with all it's files it needs to be modified but it didn't seem like you needed it